# Joining two consecutive lines using awk or sed

Tags: unix, sed, awk

How would I join two lines using awk or sed?

I have data that looks like this:

```
abcd
joinabcd
efgh
joinefgh
ijkl
joinijkl
```

I need an output like the one below:

```
joinabcdabcd
joinefghefgh
joinijklijkl
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
awk '!(NR%2){print$0p}{p=$0}' infile
```

Comment: Would anybody care to explain how this awk expression works?  Mostly the !(NR%2) part.

Comment: NR represents the number of rows... 
% is the modulu operator (i.e. a%b is the remainder when a is divided by b)...
(NR%2) is the modulu of NR by two, i.e. is true when NR is even and false when odd...
!(NR%2) is true when NR is odd, thus...
!(NR%2){print$0p} means the program will print the line concatenated with the variable p, only on odd lines...
{p=$0} means that on every line, p is set to be the current line (but only after printing the current and previous line if the current line is odd).

Comment: With an odd number of input lines, this method will not print the final line.

Comment: @BryonNicoson, correct, even though the OP sample seemed to have even number of lines. This would handle odd number of lines: `awk 'END{if((NR%2))print p}!(NR%2){print$0p}{p=$0}'`

Answer (score 10):

You can use printf with a ternary:

```
    awk '{printf (NR%2==0) ? $0 "\n" : $0}'
```

Comment: This answer doesn't give the correct result. For example, the OP requires *joinabcdabcd* for the first line but this one-liner outputs *abcdjoinabcd*. But if alternating consecutive concatenation is what you want, then the easiest solution is `lam - - <file` *(lam(1) is a helpful utility from the 4.2BSD era)*.

Comment: This doesn't work if the input file contains format specifiers, such as `%s`.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1}{line[i++]=$0}END{j=1; while (j<i) {print line[j+1] line[j]; j+=2}}' yourfile
```

No need for sed.

Comment: Good answer....but i suppose i asked for complete line not just the first field.so now it need to be changed as `line[i++]=$0` instead of `line[i++]=$1`.But a very good answer thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

Here it is in sed:

```
sed 'h;s/.*//;N;G;s/\n//g' < filename
```

Comment: The redirection is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

They say imitation is the sincerest form of flattery.
Here's a Perl solution inspired by Dimitre's awk code:

```
perl -lne 'print "$_$p" if $. % 2 == 0; $p = $_' infile
```

`$_` is the current line
`$.` is the line number

Answer (score 1):

Some improvement to the "sed" script above that will take the       following:
1008
-2734406.132904 
2846
-2734414.838455 
4636
-2734413.594009 
6456
-2734417.316269 
8276
-2734414.779617

```
  and make it :
```

1008 -2734406.132904
2846 -2734414.838455
4636 -2734413.594009
6456 -2734417.316269
8276 -2734414.779617

```
  the "sed" is : "sed 'h;s/.*//;G;N;s/\n/ /g'"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to the question "How to make the count and the file appear on the same line" in the command:

```
find . -type f -exec fgrep -ci "MySQL" {} \; -print
```

Bryon Nicolson's answer produced the best result.