# Make lines from a file into rows

Tags: linux, unix

I have file as below;

```
roger
"supplier"
anger
"easter"
robin
"badguy"
sweety
"i like you"
goldy
"I hate you"
```

I need this file to be converted into something like

```
roger|supplier
anger|easter
robin|badguy
sweety|i like you
goldy|I hate you
```

Please help, I am thing of putting it thru a awhile loop and read them into 2 different files and then concatenate the files. I know that's not a great idea hence posting for some suggestions.

Comment: this is kind of a vague question, but sounds like a job for awk

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please explain more.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194534/joining-two-consecutive-lines-awk-sed

Comment: @user2999920: the file that i have currently is in format:
process_name
process_desc
which i need in one single line
as  process_name|process_desc

Comment: @AlG: I feel its a little different, but i am looking at the solutions offered in there. thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR%2{a=$0;next}{print a,$2}' FS='"' OFS='|' file
roger|supplier
anger|easter
robin|badguy
sweety|i like you
goldy|I hate you
```

Or slightly shorter with `xargs` and `sed`:

```
$ xargs -n2 < file | sed 's/ /|/'
roger|supplier
anger|easter
robin|badguy
sweety|i like you
goldy|I hate you
```

Or just `sed`:

```
$ sed '$!N;s/\n/|/;s/"//g' file
roger|supplier
anger|easter
robin|badguy
sweety|i like you
goldy|I hate you
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
echo 'roger
"supplier"
anger
"easter"
robin
"badguy"
sweety
"i like you"
goldy
"I hate you"' \
| awk '{
   if (NR%2){
     printf("%s", $0)
   }
   else {
     gsub(/"/,"", $0);printf("|%s\n", $0)
   }
 }'
```

**output**

```
roger|supplier
anger|easter
robin|badguy
sweety|i like you
goldy|I hate you
```