# how to sort this in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Hello I have a file containing these lines:

```
apple
12
orange
4
rice
16
```

how to use bash to sort it by numbers ?
Suppose each number is the price for the above object.

I want they are formatted like this:

```
12 apple
4 orange
16 rice
```

or

```
apple 12
orange 4
rice 16
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *solution* using `paste` + `sort` to get each product *sorted by its price*:

```
$ paste - -  < file|sort -k 2nr
rice    16
apple   12
orange  4
```

**Explanation**

From `paste`  **man**:

> Write lines consisting of the **sequentially corresponding lines from
>   each FILE**, separated by TABs, to standard output.   **With no FILE, or
>   when FILE  is -, read standard input.**

`paste` gets the stream coming from the `stdin` (*your* `<file`) and figures that each line *belongs* to the *fictional* archive represented by  `-` , so we get **two** columns using `- -`

`sort` use the flag `-k 2nr` to get `paste` output *sorted* by second column in *reverse numerical* order.

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk:

```
awk '!(NR%2){printf "%s %s\n" ,$0 ,p}{p=$0}' inputfile
```

(slightly adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3196948/2082964))

If you want to sort the output afterwards, you can use `sort` (quite logically):

```
awk '!(NR%2){printf "%s %s\n" ,$0 ,p}{p=$0}' inputfile | sort -n
```

this would give:

```
4 orange
12 apple
16 rice
```

Comment: dinging this solution for ( 1 ) having to use `modulo %` operator, ( 2 ) splitting unnecessary fields, and ( 3 ) `p` updates every row when it should've been every other row

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `awk`

```
$ awk '/[0-9]+/{print prev, $0; next} {prev=$0}' input
apple 12
orange 4
rice 16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r line1 && read -r line2;do
    printf '%s %s\n' "$line1" "$line2"
done < input_file
```

If you want lines to be sorted by price, pipe the result to `sort -k2`:

```
while read -r line1 && read -r line2;do
    printf '%s %s\n' "$line1" "$line2"
done < input_file | sort -k2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `paste` and `awk`

```
$ paste - - <lines.txt | awk '{printf("%s %s\n",$2,$1)}'
12 apple
4 orange
16 rice
```

Comment: If you are using Awk anyway, you can get rid of the `paste` trivially; but then this simply repeats solutions from earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

an `awk`-based solution without needing external `paste / sort`, using `regex`, calculating `modulo %` of anything, or `awk/bash` loops

> ```
> {m,g}awk '(_*=--_) ? (__ = $!_)<__ : ($++NF = __)_' FS='\n'
> ```

```
12 apple
4 orange
16 rice
```