# Why is my text file displaying all of my fields as being equal to only one field?

Tags: bash, file, awk, field

I am using bash to file-carve a text file with (theoretically) four fields: MD5, Timestamp, Hostname and Filepath. Each of these fields sits right above one another as shown in the output below. When I perform the following command I have output that returns 1 for every field.

```
awk '{print NF, "- " $1}' best_file.txt
```

Output:

```
1 - md5:XXXXXXXX
1 - timestamp:XXXXXXXX
1 - endpoint:XXXXXXXX
1 - filename:XXXXXXXX
1 - md5:XXXXXXXX
1 - timestamp:XXXXXXXX
1 - endpoint:XXXXXXXX
1 - filename:XXXXXXXX
```

I am trying to carve my file and organize it however I choose with those four fields. For example, when using `cut` or 'awk' I cannot specify which field to `cut` or `awk` because it all appears as 1 field.

I would like to have the option to present MD5's and hostnames right next to each other, or filename's and timestamps side-by-side. Any help to understand why all of my fields are being presented as 1 field would be appreciated. Once again, I would expect 4, but its all showing up as one...

Comment: Could you please show a sample of best_file.txt

Comment: What do you mean when you say the file _theoretically_ has 4 fields?  Does it or doesn't it? In order for anyone to answer your question, you will need to include a sample of the input file, best_file.txt.

Comment: You say these fields sit above each other. Fields are counted within the same row of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I produced analogous output with `best_file.txt` containing

```
md5:XXXX
timestamp:XXXX
endpoint:XXXX
filename:XXXX
```

It is unclear whether those key names are actually in your source. For files of this sort, I do not recommend it.

Documentation on `print NF` noted that the fields are **space-delimited**. Change the first line of that to `md5 XXXX` and the corresponding output is:

```
2 -  md5
```

where `print NF` gives the number of fields, $1 is the first field and $2 is the second (outputs XXXX in this case). So your file only has one space-delimited field per line, which is a problem when awk runs these commands once per line (record).

If it was 'md5:XXXX timestamp:XXXX endpoint:XXXX filename:XXXX', then I could run `awk '{print NF ": " $1 " " $3}' best_file.txt` to get

```
4: md5:XXXX endpoint:XXXX
```

Of course, that may not be under your control. You could:

**1. Combine groups of lines into one**

You can get an arbitrary number of fields on one line with `awk '!(NR%4){print p " " $0, p=""}(NR%4){p=p " " $0}' best_file.txt` (requires some adjustment to get rid of the leading space; [Joining two consecutive lines using awk or sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194534/joining-two-consecutive-lines-using-awk-or-sed) explains the commands). Then you can have a more useful input file.

**2. Hunt for the lines you want**

Adding more precise conditions to the second block of that snippet, you can choose which lines (fields) to remember for printing.

Both approaches fail if the source file is missing a line somewhere. Actually parsing the keys will require a good deal more logic.